# Highlight live search results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight the text that matches the query in a live search using [jquery.highlight](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html). The live search works fine but the styling for the highlighting applies then it disappears. Am I doing something wrong?

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").bind("keyup", function() {
    var form = $(this).parents("form");
    var query = $(this).val();
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.post("/questions/new/search", formData, function(html) { 
      $("#questionList").html(html);
    });

    $(".question").highlight(query);
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/questions" method="get">
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
</form>

<div id="questionList">
    <div class="question">What is the 1 + 1?</div>
    <div class="answers">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should execute `$(".question").highlight(query)` in the http request response handler right after `$("#questionList").html(html)` this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").bind("keyup", function() {
    var form = $(this).parents("form");
    var query = $(this).val();
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.post("/questions/new/search", formData, function(html) { 
      $("#questionList").html(html);
      $(".question").highlight(query);
    });

  });
});
```